# vue js не обновляет параметр из $data

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет. Помогите разобраться со vuejs.
Суть задачи: есть грид, в каждой ячейки есть кнопка "добавить элемент", по ее нажатию всплывает модальное окно с select'ом. После выбора нужного параметра в модал. окне кликается кнопка "добавить" и в этой же ячейки должен появиться div с названием выбранного элемента (это вкратце)

Принцип работы: грид, ячейка, кнопка, модал. окно - отдельный компоненты. В  гриде есть массив, хранящий все добавленные элементы для всего грида. У каждой ячейки есть свой id, по которому происходит добавление. 
В модал. окне срабатывает событие на клик по кнопке, оно вызывает событие у кнопки, кнопка у ячейки, ячейка у грида, а грид при этом передает ячейке полный список всех добавленных элементов :)

Куски кода:

**Грид:**

```
<template>
<div>
    {{ elements }}
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <cell id="one" :onAdded="addElement" :elements="elements"></cell>
            <cell id="two" :onAdded="addElement" :elements="elements"></cell>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            elements: {}
        };
    },
    methods: {
        addElement: function(cellId, name) {
            console.log('В ячейку', cellId, 'нужно добавить элемент', name);
            let elements = this.elements;
            if(typeof elements[cellId] === 'undefined') elements[cellId] = [];
            elements[cellId].push({name});
            this.$set(this.elements, elements);
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Ячейка:**

```
<template>
<td>
    <div class="panel panel-default"
         v-if="typeof elements[id] !== 'undefined'"
         v-for="element in elements[id]"
    >
        {{ element.name }}
    </div>
    <add-element-button :id="id" :onSuccess="addElement"/>
</td>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
export default {
    props: {
        id: {type: String, required: true},
        onAdded: {type: Function, required: true},
        elements: {type: Object, default: function() {
            return {};
        }}
    },
    methods: {
        addElement: function(id, name, params) {
            this.onAdded(id, name);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Данный код срабатывает только в первый раз. Вначале грида вывожу полный список элементов. Сначала выводится пустой, после первого добавления, элемент появляется. Все, что добавляется потом, в массив не попадает.

То есть код: console.log('В ячейку', cellId, 'нужно добавить элемент', name); из грида выполняется всегда корректно, но элементы не перерисовываются на странице. Подскажите как заставить vue перерисовать все элементы или может нужно не $set(...) использовать, а что-то другое? уже всю голову сломал. Заранее благодарен

Comment: кстати, при добавлении второго элемента, watch тоже не срабатывает для elements

Comment: Да есть такая проблема: 1) если у объекта нет свойств они не биндятся, если хочешь что б прибиндились луше попробуй по одному их туда биндить `this.$set(this.elements,'field','value')` и так далее т.е. внутри будет `this.$set(this.elements.field,'childField','value1')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказывается, вся проблема была в экземпляре объекта. Когда присваиваешь "дубликат" объекта этому же объекту, то ничего не выходит. След. код работать не будет:

```
let a = this.b;
a.key = 'new_value';
this.$set(this.b, a);
```

Параметр b все равно не поменяется. Вместо этого, необходимо создавать новый объект (клонировать текущий):

```
let a = {};
// Здесь запускаем for и восстанавливаем экземпляр this.b в переменной a.
a.key = 'new_value';
this.$set(this.b, a);
```

Второй пример отработает как надо